# Error registering client_id and client_secret with Autodesk Forge

Tags: curl, autodesk-forge, clientid

I am working on getting a 2-legged token for my app using [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-2-legged-token/) tutorial. I have followed the procedure and replaced my client_ID and client_secret values. However, I get a HTTP Bad Request error (please see the diagram below). The error message is:

```
"The required parameter(s) client_id,client_secret,grant_type not present in the request"
```

However, as can be seen in the diagram, I have clearly included them in the code. Can anyone point out whats going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, you dont have to put spaces between client_ID, client_secret, grant_type etc. You only have to separate them by '&' symbol. An example is as follows:

```
curl -v "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate" -X "POST" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "client_id=Pf4JpuXXXXXXXXXXXXo1QvEfr&client_secret=Mb6dXXXXXXXXXXXX&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=data:read"
```

Comment: Technically you need  your content to be delimited by `&` so that it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as required by our service.